# Core Data with both static pre-populated and dynamic user data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my project I have pre-populated data in Core Data, ie. I have a sqlite file that's copied into user's folder on first launch, however I also have user data which user generates, in this case is there anyway I can use a single data model? I know I can create two models one static and one for user but just wondering if there's a better way.
Thanks!

update:
My concern is although it works for the first release, in subsequent releases if I need to update the static data, it would be a new sqlite file that's copied into user folder which will overwrite existing user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Question: *[...] can I use a single data model?*

Yes. There is the concept of *Configurations* with Core Data Models. You can learn about it here: [NSManagedObjectModel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectmodel). This allows you to partition one data model into several parts. For the use case described in the OP you want have two parts or configurations: "StaticData" and "UserData". "StaticData" holds entities and data that may change only with App updates (*new releases*). "UserData" holds user data. You need to design data and foreign keys accordingly in a manner that the entities of both data sets are "well linked" for the App's lifetime. (If you cannot ensure this from the beginning to the end you need to design additional data migration processing for each release).

2. Question/Use Case: Only update static data not overwrite user data.

Each "Configuration" (see 1.) will have a persistent core data store (*SQLite file*) for its own. For the use case specified the file with user data must not be excluded from the backup but the static data must be excluded from the backup. You can learn about how to exclude files and directories from backups here: [NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlisexcludedfrombackupkey). After a new release the empty user data will be overwritten with the user data from the backup.